# Allow parallel running of php script

Tags: php, mysql, parallel-processing

There is about 10 request to php script in one minute, and want to run one calculation each min. I can't use cron. 
So I did: 
If last calculation time is older than 60 seconds do:

- Save last calculation time to MySQL before calculation
- Do calculation
- Save last calculation after calculation ends.

Problem: if two (or tree) requests are running at the same second, two (or tree) calculation are executed.

**EDIT:** How to make run computation only once a minute? I there any way in PHP to find out how many times currently the script running?

Comment: And what is the question? :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would use a cron :) I understand you can't.

Try this, when you find a calculation is old, put a general flag that is in progress so no other calculation would start but it will use the old value. When you are done update the value remove the flag.

Basically when a calculation is running no other one will start and you remove the parallelism problem.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I think I do this since I update last calc. time (first list item). I don't know why, but it doesnt work, if two requests run in a same second

Comment: Yes, but even less then a second, you check and update, that will probably be less then a quarter of a second. If you have 10 users every 60 seconds that is about 1 every 6 seconds, some will probably calculate twice, but that number is way lower then you think.